# How to negate an evaluation/expression in helm?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have bash commands that copies files and folders to a target directory. After all files/folders are copied, I need to check if I need to delete a specific folder. If `false`, delete the directory. In helm, how do I negate the boolean `true` or `false`

Something like:

```
{{- if not .Values.copyExamples }}
    --delete the files
{{- end }}
```

Comment: Your assumption is correct. You can see this example from a stable helm chart to verify: https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/9d5ff6627089fa1bbf6f0c4e38a6b3135158bf2c/stable/traefik/templates/deployment.yaml#L22

Answer (score 22):

You can negate a test on a single value using the simple syntax:

```
{{- if not .Values.ssl.upstream }}
```

If you need to negate the result of a comparison then you can also do that:

```
{{- if not (contains "test" $env) }}
```